# Is SQL Server lock on RID locking more than one row

Tags: sql-server, locking

I wanted to recreate a deadlock on a single table, by enforcing exclusive lock at the row level. I created a table `Foo` and inserted two rows. Then I created 2 sessions each with a transaction.

In session 1 I wanted to start with an update of row 1, and in session 2 an update of row 2. Now what happened was that session 2 ended up waiting for session 1s update to finish.

Looking at `dm_trans_lock` however I can see that an X lock on RID was acquired for session 1, and that session 2 is waiting.

I thought a row lock was a lock on row? What is happening?

Comment: Hard to say without sample scripts, but it could session 2 need to read "row 1" as part of its query plan.

Comment: Please show your sample code.